# Get details from on delegate function that has thrown an error

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am using delegates to solve an issue I have. I am currently only in testing but I have the following

```
public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Runner<myEntity>();
        var results = test.RunGetAll(GetAll);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<myEntity> GetAll()
    {
        var uow = new CacheUnitOfWork(new DatabaseContext());
        throw new Exception("Error");
        return GetEntities(uow);
    }        
}

public class Runner<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> RunGetAll(Func<IEnumerable<T>> myMethodName)
    {            
        try
        {
            var test = myMethodName.Invoke();
            return test;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // I want to figure out here what type of unit of work I am using
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }            
    }        
}
```

As you see, My delagate function being used is the `GetAll()` function in the `Main`.

I am forcing it to error. In the try catch block below I am catching this error. What I want to do is check what Unit of work I am using and then use another unit of work. So in this case I am using the `CacheUnitOfWork`. I will want to change this to a `DBUnitOfWork`.

Is there anything I can use. Reflection?

Comment: no you can't check what Unit of work you use inside compiled function

Comment: You could create your own customer `Exception` type, and include some extra information within the exception to pass it out into whatever catches it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? Separation of concerns is necessary sometimes, shouln't `GetAll` handle the exception as well? The runner really shouldn't know what it is wrapping / running.